# how can i change the image in my collection view by tapping on media player in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a collection view and a button in my view controller I want to change the image in my collection view by tapping on my button, but it is proving quite difficult.I have made it so when i click on my collection view my button image changes now i want to do vice versa. Any help would be appreciated

```
import UIKit
import SwiftAudioPlayer
import Soundable
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import MediaPlayer
import Kingfisher

protocol poorBtn: AnyObject {
func poorBtnTapped(sender: UIButton!)
}

class SongsViewController: BaseViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var forYouView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var noSongsLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var navView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var albumCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var songsCollection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var songProgress: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var startTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var songDetailView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderProgress: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var forwardBtn: UIButton!

weak var delegate: poorBtn?
var play = false
var isplaying = false
let Parent = UIViewController()
var selectedIndex : Int?
let playList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

var albums : [String] = ["manHat", "manHat","manHat", "manHat"]
var albumLbl : [String] = ["George Harrison", "George Harrison","George Harrison", 
"George Harrison"]

var songs : [String] = ["Geazy", "manHat","Geazy", "manHat"]
var playImage : [String] = ["wPause","wPause","wPause","wPause","wPause"]
var timer: Timer?
var index: Int = Int()
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var isPaused: Bool!
var didPlayed: Bool!
var isTapped: Bool!
var audio: AVAudioPlayer!
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem!
var music : [String] = ["https://p.scdn.co/mp3- 
preview/6f9999d909b017eabef97234dd7a206355720d9d? 
cid=d8a5ed958d274c2e8ee717e6a4b0971d","https://p.scdn.co/mp3- 
preview/081447adc23dad4f79ba4f1082615d1c56edf5e1? 
cid=d8a5ed958d274c2e8ee717e6a4b0971d"]
var counter: Timer?
var currentCellIndex = 0
var getSender: Int = Int()
var pop = false
var ploy = true
var newSender = 0
var isPlaying: Int?
var realSender: Int = Int()
var isPlay: Int?
var forPrev: Int?
var mainPlay: Int?
var playingIndex: Int?
 
lazy var viewModel:ForYouSongsViewModel = {
    let viewModel = ForYouSongsViewModel()
    viewModel.delegate = self
    return viewModel
}()

var forSongs = [String]()
var currentIndex : Int?
var forImages = [ForYou]()
var albumImages = [Album]()
var albumId: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    sliderProgress.setValue(0, animated: true)
    self.startLoading()
    albumCollection.delegate = self
    albumCollection.dataSource = self
    
    songsCollection.delegate = self
    songsCollection.dataSource = self
    isPaused = false
       songDetailView.layer.mask = maskLayer
   
    viewModel.getForYouSongs()
//        counter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: 
  #selector(slider), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.setUpNavView()
  }

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
//test
@IBAction func backTap(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
       // self.avPlayer = nil
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

@objc func slider() {
    if forImages.isEmpty == true {
        print("Sadly it's empty")
        forYouView.isHidden = true
        songsCollection.isHidden = true
        noSongsLbl.text = "No Songs"
    } else {
        noSongsLbl.isHidden = true
        if currentCellIndex < forSongs.count - 1 {
            currentCellIndex+=1
        
        }
        else {
            currentCellIndex = 0
        }
    songsCollection.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: currentCellIndex, section: 0), 
at: .right, animated: true)
}
}

@IBAction func playBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
   
    //delegate?.poorBtnTapped(sender: sender)
    isPlay = 1
    mainPlay = playingIndex
    print(mainPlay)
    if play == false {
        self.startLoading()
        guard let songUrlString = forSongs[self.index] as? String else {return}
        guard let songUrl = URL(string:songUrlString) else{return}
        print(songUrlString)
        print(songUrl)
       
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        //NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("playSong"), 
object: nil)
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        tick()
        play = true
        didPlayed = false
    }
    else if isplaying == true {
       // playSaveSound()
        avPlayer?.play()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
       // NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("playSong"), 
object: nil)

        isplaying = false
        tick()
    }
    else {
        avPlayer?.pause()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        isplaying = true
    }
    
    self.setupTimer()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("songPlay"), object: nil)
    songsCollection.reloadData()
  }

@IBAction func forwardBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.startLoading()
    self.nextTrack()
  
  }

@IBAction func backBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.startLoading()
    self.prevTrack()


}

func playSong(url:URL) {
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.avPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    avPlayer!.volume = 1.0
    avPlayer.play()
    setupNowPlaying()
    setupRemoteCommandCenter()
    self.stopLoading()
}

func setupTimer(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.didPlayToEnd), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: 
#selector(SongsViewController.tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}


@objc func didPlayToEnd() {
    self.startLoading()
    self.nextTrack()
}

@IBAction func sliderTapped(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let seconds : Int64 = Int64(sender.value)
    let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
    avPlayer?.seek(to: targetTime)
}

@objc func tick() {
    //print(avPlayer)
    if((avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration) != nil){
        if let _ = avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration{}else{return}
        if let _ = avPlayer.currentItem?.currentTime(){}else{return}
        let currentTime1 : CMTime = (avPlayer.currentItem?.asset.duration)!
        let seconds1 : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime1)
        let time1 : Float = Float(seconds1)
        sliderProgress.minimumValue = 0
        sliderProgress.maximumValue = time1
        let currentTime : CMTime = (self.avPlayer?.currentTime())!
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)
        guard !(seconds.isNaN || seconds.isInfinite) else {
                              return
                           }
        let time : Float = Float(seconds)
        self.sliderProgress.value = time
        endTime.text =  self.formatTimeFromSeconds(totalSeconds: 



  [enter image description here] 


[1]Int32(Float(Float64(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer?.currentItem?.asset.duration)! 
)))).   )
        startTime.text = self.formatTimeFromSeconds(totalSeconds: 




 Int32(Float(Float64(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer?.currentItem?.currentTime())!)) 
 )))
    }else{
        if let duration = (self.avPlayer?.currentItem?.duration) {
                        let secs = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                        guard !(secs.isNaN || secs.isInfinite) else {
                               return
                            }
                        let secondsText = Int(secs.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 
 60.0))
                        let minutesText = Int(secs / 60)
                        self.endTime.text = "\(minutesText):\(secondsText)"
    }
    }
}

func nextTrack(){
    if(index < forSongs.count-1){
        index = index + 1
        isPaused = false
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: URL(string:(forSongs[self.index] ))!)
    }else{
        index = 0
        isPaused = false
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: URL(string:(forSongs[self.index] ))!)
    }
}

 func prevTrack(){
    if(index > 0){
        index = index - 1
        isPaused = false
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: URL(string:(forSongs[self.index] as! String))!)
    }
 }

func formatTimeFromSeconds(totalSeconds: Int32) -> String {
    let seconds: Int32 = totalSeconds%60
    let minutes: Int32 = (totalSeconds/60)%60
   // let hours: Int32 = totalSeconds/3600
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds)
}

 private func setUpNavView(){
    let btnGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let colorTop = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 
 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 6.0/255.0, green: 47.0/255.0, blue: 79.0/255.0, 
 alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.1)
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    let frame = self.navView.bounds
    
    btnGradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    btnGradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
    btnGradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
    btnGradientLayer.frame = frame
    navView.backgroundColor = .red
    self.navView.layer.insertSublayer(btnGradientLayer, at: 0)
    self.navView.clipsToBounds = false
  }

@IBAction func playPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton!) {
    
    self.selectedIndex = sender.tag
    self.isTapped = true

 }
//FOR NOTIFICATION

func setupNowPlaying() {
    // Define Now Playing Info
    var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = forImages[0].title
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = "G-Eazy"
    if let movieArt = UIImage(named: "Geazy") {
         nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: 
 movieArt.size, requestHandler: {
               imageSize in return movieArt })
         }
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream] = false
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = 
 playerItem.currentTime().seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = 
 playerItem.asset.duration.seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = avPlayer.rate
    
    // Set the metadata
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .playing
 }
 func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared();
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.avPlayer.play()
        self.playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.setupTimer()

        return .success
    }
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.avPlayer.pause()
        self.playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
      //  self.tick()
        self.setupTimer()
        return .success
    }
   }

}

extension SongsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {


//FOR ALBUM COLLECTION

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.albumCollection {
        return albumImages.count
    }
    return forSongs.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if collectionView == self.albumCollection {
    let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "album", for: 
indexPath) as! AlbumsCollectionViewCell
        if albumImages.isEmpty != true {
        let albumUrl = URL(string: albumImages[indexPath.row].image)
        cellA.albumImg.kf.setImage(with: albumUrl)
        cellA.albumLbl.text = albumImages[indexPath.row].name
        }
        
    return cellA
    }
    else {
        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "songs", 
for: indexPath) as! ForYouCollectionViewCell
        
      
        let songUrl = URL(string: forImages[indexPath.row].image)
        cellB.forImg.kf.setImage(with: songUrl)
        cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: playImage[indexPath.row]), for: 
.normal)
        cellB.songTitle.text = forImages[indexPath.row].title
        cellB.forButton.tag = indexPath.row
        if indexPath.row == isPlaying {
            cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: .normal)
        }
        
//            if isPlay == nil {
//                print("I'm a noob")
//
//            } else {
//                if playImg.image == UIImage(named: "play") {
//                    cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: 
.normal)
//                } else {
//                    cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
//                    isPlay = nil
//                }
//    

    }
        if mainPlay != nil {
            if cellB.forButton.image(for: .normal) == UIImage(named: "wPause") {
                cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
                
            } else {
                cellB.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: .normal)
                mainPlay = nil
            }
        }
        cellB.delegate = self
        cellB.btnTapped
        return cellB
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "songs", for: 
  indexPath) as! ForYouCollectionViewCell
    currentIndex = indexPath.row
    if collectionView  == self.albumCollection {
        if didPlayed == false {
        avPlayer.pause()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
            //avPlayer = nil
        timer?.invalidate()
            self.presentAlbumCollectionController(fromController: self, withAId: 
forImages[indexPath.row].album_id)
        } else {
            self.presentAlbumCollectionController(fromController: self, withAId: 
forImages[indexPath.row].album_id)
            }
        
}
    isPlaying = indexPath.row
    songsCollection.reloadData()
    
    guard let songUrlString = forSongs[indexPath.row] as? String else {return}
    guard let songUrl = URL(string:songUrlString) else{return}
    print(songUrlString)
    print(songUrl)
    print(indexPath.row)
    print(playList.count)
    
      if play == false && getSender == indexPath.row {
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        play = true
        getSender = indexPath.row
        pop = false
        ploy = true

    } else if getSender == indexPath.row{
        avPlayer?.pause()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        play = false
        getSender = indexPath.row
        isPlaying = nil
    } else if newSender == indexPath.row && ploy == false {
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        play = false
        pop = true
        ploy = true
    }
     else if pop == true {
        avPlayer?.pause()
         
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        play = false
        pop = false
         isPlaying = nil
    } else {
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        if realSender == getSender {
        pop = false
        }
        ploy = true
        getSender = indexPath.row
        play = true
    }
    
//        if mainPlay != nil {
//            if cell.forButton.image(for: .normal) == UIImage(named: "wPause") {
//                cell.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPlay"), for: .normal)
//            } else {
//                cell.forButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "wPause"), for: .normal)
//            }
//        }
        playingIndex = indexPath.row
        self.setupTimer()
// 

   songsCollection.reloadData()
}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                            willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                            forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   
   cell.alpha = 0
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
       cell.alpha = 1
   }
 }

 /* func conditions() {
    
    if play == false {
        
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        tick()
       // SongTime()
        play = true
    }
    else if isplaying == true {
       // playSaveSound()
        avPlayer?.play()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        isplaying = false
        tick()
  
   //SongTime()
    }
    else {
        avPlayer?.pause()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        isplaying = true
    }
  } */
  }
 extension SongsViewController:SongDelegate {
  func songBtnTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
      isPlaying = sender.tag
    songsCollection.reloadData()
    
    guard let songUrlString = forSongs[sender.tag] as? String else {return}
    guard let songUrl = URL(string:songUrlString) else{return}
    print(songUrlString)
    print(songUrl)
    print(sender.tag)
    print(playList.count)
    
      if play == false && getSender == sender.tag {
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        play = true
        getSender = sender.tag
        pop = false
        ploy = true

    } else if getSender == sender.tag{
        avPlayer?.pause()
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        play = false
        getSender = sender.tag
        isPlaying = nil
    } else if newSender == sender.tag && ploy == false {
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        play = false
        pop = true
        ploy = true
    }
     else if pop == true {
        avPlayer?.pause()
         
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "play")
        play = false
        pop = false
         isPlaying = nil
    } else {
        playImg.image = UIImage(named: "pause")
        self.playSong(url: songUrl)
        tick()
        if realSender == getSender {
        pop = false
        }
        ploy = true
        getSender = sender.tag
        play = true
    }
    self.setupTimer()
   }
 }
```

Comment: You want to change the image in a specific cell?

Comment: Yes  I want to change the image of the cell that was playing in the index

Comment: You can use reloadItems(at:) method. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditems